# My else statement is always an invalid syntax

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax, syntax-error

I follow a course "web programming" and I'm stuck in Python. My "else" statement always gives an error (invalid syntax). No matter which code I try (any random code I use from the web), I always get the same error with my else statement. This is a very simple code which gives the error:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

test1 = 2
test2 = 1

if test1 < test2:
    print("Is smaller")
elif test1 > test2:
    print("is bigger")
else test1 == test2:
    print("is equal")
```

---

This is what I get in Terminal:

```
  File "varvergelijken3.py", line 10
    else test1 == test2:
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: else doesn't carry conditional

Comment: Your `test1 == test2:` is pointless, if it is not > or < it has to be equal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` clause does not take an argument - it's executed if and only if the `if` condition and all the `elif` conditions are not met. You could use another `elif` condition:

```
if test1 < test2:
    print("Is smaller")
elif test1 > test2:
    print("is bigger")
elif test1 == test2:
    print("is equal")
```

Or, since if neither `test1` is smaller than `test2`, nor `test2` smaller than `test1`, they must be equal, so a simple `else` condition would suffice:

```
if test1 < test2:
    print("Is smaller")
elif test1 > test2:
    print("is bigger")
else:
    print("is equal")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test1 = 2
test2 = 1

if test1 < test2:
    print("Is smaller")
elif test1 > test2:
    print("is bigger")
elif test1 == test2:
    print("is equal")
```

else doesn't carry conditional

or more desirably

```
test1 = 2
test2 = 1

if test1 < test2:
    print("Is smaller")
elif test1 > test2:
    print("is bigger")
else:
    print("is equal")
```

**to learn more, refer to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html)**

Answer (score 1):

else doesnt have a condition in python, you can do :

```
if test1 < test2:
    print("Is smaller")
elif test1 > test2:
    print("is bigger")
else:
    print("is equal")
```

or if you want to specify the condition than do:

```
if test1 < test2:
    print("Is smaller")
elif test1 > test2:
    print("is bigger")
elif test1 == test2:
    print("is equal")
```